# Firestore-algolia-search command not found

Tags: firebase, command-line, algolia

So I had a question  I'm working on a Algolia extension for Firebase but when I try Step 3(see image 2 below) to excute the commands I get a "bash: firestore-algolia-search: command not found" error even though I installed the npx does anyone know why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can run npx firestore-algolia-search but when the run it with the full script it says command not found

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be solved by changing the bash command script - make this whole script into one line and remove the "\" symbols.

So change this

```
  LOCATION=YOUR-DATA\
  PROJECT_ID=YOUR-DATA\
  ALGOLIA_APP_ID=YOUR-DATA\
  ALGOLIA_API_KEY=YOUR-DATA\
  ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME=YOUR-DATA\
  COLLECTION_PATH=YOUR-DATA\
  FIELDS=YOUR-DATA\
  TRANSFORM_FUNCTION=YOUR-DATA\
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=YOUR-DATA\
  npx firestore-algolia-search
```

to this

```
LOCATION=YOUR-DATA PROJECT_ID=YOUR-DATA ALGOLIA_APP_ID=YOUR-DATA ALGOLIA_API_KEY=YOUR-DATA ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME=YOUR-DATA COLLECTION_PATH=YOUR-DATA FIELDS=YOUR-DATA TRANSFORM_FUNCTION=YOUR-DATA GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=YOUR-DATA npx firestore-algolia-search
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, you can stop this issue by making sure you path does not have <> around it. That said the function still doesn't seem to have worked for me, but this at least got around the "command not found" error.